# Birth control in times of old

Tags: history, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

Nowadays there are many halachically permissible birth control methods that are available (pills, diaphragms, coils, etc.) that were not available in the past. Aside from the natural means of menstruation regulation (e.g. breastfeeding) what methods of birth control were practiced (that were halachically acceptable) before the modern medical revolution? I am interested in answers that include male **and** female birth control intervention.

A wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_condoms) suggests a male form of birth control that may have been used in the middle ages:

> In the writings of Muslims and Jews during the Middle Ages, there are some references to attempts at male-controlled contraception, including suggestions to cover the penis in tar or soak it in onion juice. Some of these writings might describe condom use, but they are "oblique", "veiled", and "vague".

I am interested in answers with a scientific basis as well as Jewish superstitions/minhagim (e.g. amulets).

Comment: משמשת במוח. עבור אשה מניקה

Comment: Off topic as being a question about historical practices (not even necessarily Jewish historical practices)?

Comment: @Salmononius2 .... this is of course a question about halachically acceptable methods of birth control before the advent of methods in modern medicine

Comment: I think abstention was the main method. In a number communities, I gather this was a "given" as the men were travelling quite a bit.

Comment: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/refua/encyc/menia.htm

Comment: Oh, goldarnit. I closed the question as not-about-Judaism because I missed that it was restricting attention to halachically permitted methods. Sorry about that. That said, since four other users voted to close before me, I'm going to let it be rather than reopen unilaterally.

Comment: The other four close votes were for "too broad" rather than off-topic.

Comment: I think the vote to close was before i edited?

Answer (score -2):

In a class on Jewish superstition years ago I read a story about a woman who would insert a small pebble into young maiden's private part (most likely her ovary) to prevent conception.   This would be a primitive form of an IUD.  I seem to recall that the story had an unhappy ending suggesting that this method of birth control was seen as "bad" or contrary to Jewish law.   I will try and find the story if I can.

Comment: She inserted a pebble into her ovary??? That seems highly unlikely.